# How to generate Powershell registry import script?

Tags: powershell, import, export, registry

Basically I simply want to right-click on a branch in Regedit and say '**Generate Powershell script for import**'. So that instead of a `.reg` file I get a PS script which will import/create elsewhere the entire selected registry branch with all keys/values etc.

I thought this would be a standard thing somewhere but I can't find anything, nor anyone with the same question, which surprises me.

Of course I could code it all out in PS but I'm feeling really lazy...

Comment: Thanks again, but I really want something far simpler like the IIS team have done (ten years ago) in IIS Admin 8: https://iis-blogs.azurewebsites.net/wonyoo/powershell-script-generation-in-iis-configuration-editor

Comment: You don't need a PowerShell script. What you really need to get the customized regedit is something to mod, reverse engeneer or customize the regedit. Then your question is far away from `show your work` as mentioned in the stackoverflow tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour -- what you could try is copy the path in regedit and paste it to your PowerShell script. Then you should try it. How should the target file look like? Show an example.

Comment: To summarize: There's no official mechanism for extending the `regedit.exe` GUI, and there's no readily available PowerShell code that generates scripts that import _embedded_ data into the registry. The answer below implements the latter as function `New-RegistryImportScript`, and the closest you can get to integration with `regedit.exe` is to _copy the key path_ (via `Copy Key Name` in the shortcut menu), switch to PowerShell session, and paste the key path as an argument to `New-RegistryImportScript` (assuming you've first defined the function there, preferably via `$PROFILE`).

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for would indeed be convenient, but, as of this writing:

- There is *no* official mechanism for customizing the `regedit.exe` utility's GUI that I'm aware of - unlike the (registry-based) mechanism for customizing *File Explorer*'s shortcut menus.

  - *Conceivably*, specialized tools / advanced WinAPI-based techniques exist to achieve that.
- Separately, there's *no* packaged PowerShell solution that I'm aware of that creates *self-contained `.ps1` scripts* that bundle registry-import code *with the data to import*.

---

Leaving the `regedit.exe` GUI-integration aspect out of the picture, the *building blocks* of what you're looking for are:

- (a) Using [`reg.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) `export` to export a given registry key's subtree to a `.reg` file.
- (b) Later using `reg.exe import` to import such a file.
- PowerShell code that combines (a) and (b) as follows:

  - It performs (a) ...
  - ... and embeds the resulting `.reg` file's *content* in a *dynamically generated script (`.ps1`)* ...
  - which, when executed on a given machine, imports the *embedded* data into the registry, via (b).

---

Below is function `New-RegistryImportScript`, which implements the steps above; here's a sample invocation:

```bash
Get-Item HKCU:\Console | New-RegistryImportScript -OutPath .
```

The above creates script `.\Import-RegKey_HKEY_CURRENT_USER_Console.ps1`, which has the data from the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` registry key (subtree) embedded and, when executed, imports that data into the registry.
The script file name was auto-generated, from the given key path, because only an output *directory* was specified to `-OutPath` (`.` to target the current dir.), but you may specify a *file* path instead, so as to use a file name of choice.

As for **`regedit.exe` integration**: Invoke **shortcut-menu command `Copy Key Name`** on the key of interest, and then pass it as an argument to `New-RegistryImportScript`; e.g.:

```bash
# 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console' is an example path copied from regedit.exe
New-RegistryImportScript HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console .
```

---

**`New-RegistryImportScript` source code**:

```bash
function New-RegistryImportScript {

<#
.SYNOPSIS
  Generates a self-contained registry-import script.

.DESCRIPTION
  Generates a self-contained registry-import script that bundles the
  data exported from a given registry key (subtree), using `reg.exe`
  behind the scenes.

  By default, the content of the generated script is output; redirect
  it to a file as needed.
  Alternatively, use -OutPath to directly save it to a file.
  If you specify a *directory*, a file name is auto-generated as
  Import-RegKey_<sanitized_key_path>.ps1, where <sanitized_key_path>
  is the input key path with all non-alphanumeric characters replaced with
  "_".

  If you provide multiple key paths via the pipeline, a *single* output file
  is created if you pass a *file* path to -OutPath.
  With a *directory* path, an auto-named script is generate for each
  input key path.

.EXAMPLE
  Get-Item HKCU:\Console | New-RegistryImportScript -OutPath .
  
  Creates automatically named script .\Import-RegKey_HKEY_CURRENT_USER_Console.ps1
  with the data exported from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console embeded in it.
#>

param(
  [Alias('PSPath')]
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)] [string] $KeyPath,
  [string] $OutPath
)
begin {
  # Code to add at the top and bottom of the generated script
  $scriptProlog = @'
[CmdletBinding()] param()

$tempFile = "$env:TEMP\" +  [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() + '.reg'

& {
'@
    $scriptEpilog = @'

} | Set-Content -Encoding Unicode -LiteralPath $tempFile
reg.exe import $tempFile
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $tempFile
exit $LASTEXITCODE
'@

  if ($env:OS -ne 'Windows_NT') { throw "This command runs on Windows only." }
  # Note: For cross-PS-edition compatibility we ensure that UTF-8 files *with BOM* are created.
  $enc = if ($IsCoreCLR) { 'utf8BOM'} else { 'utf8 '}
  $autoGenerateName = $OutPath -and (Test-Path -Type Container -LiteralPath $OutPath)
  if (-not $OutPath) {
    $scriptProlog # Output the prolog to the success output stream.
  } elseif (-not $autoGenerateName) {
    if (($parentPath = (Split-Path -Parent $OutPath)) -and -not (Test-Path -Type Container -LiteralPath $parentPath)) {
      throw "Cannot find part of the output path: $OutPath"
    }
    Write-Verbose "Generating script `"$($outFile.FullName)`"..."
    # Initialize the single output file.
    $scriptProlog | Set-Content -LiteralPath $OutPath -Encoding $enc
  }

}
process {
  # First, try to convert to a full, provider-native path.
  $nativeRegPath = Convert-Path -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $KeyPath
  if (-not $nativeRegPath) { $nativeRegPath = $KeyPath } # Assume that a native registry path was directly given.
  # Resolve it to a full, native registry path via a Get-Item call.
  # By using "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::" as the prefix, we rule out non-registry paths.
  # !! Sadly, even the .Name property does NOT contain the *case-exact* form of the key path - it reflects the case *as specified*.
  # !! However, given that the registry is inherently case-INsensitive, this should not matter.
  $nativeRegPath = (Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::$nativeRegPath").Name
  if (-not $nativeRegPath) {
    "Not an (existing) registry path: `"$KeyPath`""
    return
  }
  Write-Verbose "Targeting registry key `"$nativeRegPath`""
  # Export the target key's subtree from the registry.
  $tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
  reg.exe export $nativeRegPath $tempFile /y >$null # Creates a UTF-16LE file.
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) {
    Write-Error "Export of registry key `"$nativeRegPath`" failed."
    return
  }
  $regFileContent = Get-Content -Raw $tempFile
  $tempFile | Remove-Item
  # Create the part of the generated script that has the exported
  # data embedded as a here-string.
  $scriptEmbeddedData = @"
  Write-Verbose "Importing into ``"$nativeRegPath``"..."
  @'
$regFileContent
'@
"@
  if (-not $OutPath) {
    $scriptEmbeddedData # output to the success output stream
  }
  else {
    if ($autoGenerateName) {
      # Auto-generate a filename for the key path at hand.
      $OutFile = Join-Path $OutPath ('Import-RegKey_' + ($nativeRegPath -replace '[^\p{L}\d]', '_') + '.ps1')
      Write-Verbose -Verbose "Generating auto-named script `"$OutFile`"..."
      $scriptProlog, $scriptEmbeddedData, $scriptEpilog | Set-Content -Encoding $enc $OutFile
    } else {
      # Append the embedded data to the single output script.
      $scriptEmbeddedData | Add-Content -Encoding $enc $OutPath
    }
  }
}

end {
  if (-not $OutPath) {
    # Output the the epilog.
    $scriptEpilog
  }
  elseif (-not $autoGenerateName) {
    # Single output file? Append the epilog.
    $scriptEpilog | Add-Content -Encoding $enc $OutPath
  }
}

}
```